# How to animate all ListBox items at the same time in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, listbox

I'm making a menu in WPF using a ListBox. I need to be able to access all the opacity properties of the textbox inside the item template of the ListBox to animate when the menu comes in. Here is my ListBox code:

```
<ListBox Name="testList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource MenuListBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuListBoxItemStyle}" Margin="-30,0">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Height="42" Click="Button_Click" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsButton}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <Grid Margin="30,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Path Grid.Column="0" Data="{Binding Icon}" Width="{Binding IconWidth}" Height="{Binding IconHeight}" Fill="White" Stretch="Uniform"
                        MaxWidth="22" MaxHeight="22" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="20"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

How would I access the TextBlock's Opacity property to animate it (with Storyboards and change on mouse move)? The ListBox is bound to a MenuItem observable collection. Only thing I can think of is to add a dependency property and bind that to the opacity, but i don't know how. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change opacity for all textBlocks, i would suggest you to have StoryBoard on ListBox itself something like this:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ListBox">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                   <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                       From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                   </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
             </EventTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
                        <Path Grid.Column="0" Data="{Binding Icon}" Width="{Binding IconWidth}" Height="{Binding IconHeight}" Fill="White" Stretch="Uniform"
                    MaxWidth="22" MaxHeight="22" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="20"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1" From="1" To="0.2"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1" From="0.2" To="1"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </TextBlock.Triggers>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

another option can be

```
<ListBox Name="testList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource MenuListBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuListBoxItemStyle}" Margin="-30,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Height="42" Click="Button_Click" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsButton}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <Grid Margin="30,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Path Grid.Column="0" Data="{Binding Icon}" Width="{Binding IconWidth}" Height="{Binding IconHeight}" Fill="White" Stretch="Uniform"
                    MaxWidth="22" MaxHeight="22" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="20"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"></Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think see what your after: when the mouse moves over the list box, **just the text** on **all** the buttons changes.

You might be able to make life simpler for yourself by triggering the storyboard from the  `IsMouseOver` property of the `ListBox`. By doing that you avoid the `EventTrigger` trickiness.

```
  <ListBox x:Name="TestList3">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
              <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                      Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},Path=IsMouseOver}"
                      Value="True">
                      <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                             AutoReverse="True" />
                          </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                      </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                      <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                            <DoubleAnimation
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                              To="1" Duration="0:0:1" />
                          </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                      </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
              </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
          </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <system:String>One</system:String>
      <system:String>Two</system:String>
    </ListBox>
```